# Typescript argument type identification

Tags: typescript, variable-types

The following code works well but I wish to rewrite it more clearly, with a Typescript idiom, if possible.

```
class Actions { actions: string[] }
type Argument = object | Actions;

export class GetFilesContext implements IExecutable {

   execute( args: Argument, response: ServerResponse<IncomingMessage> ): void {
      ...
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
      if( args && args.hasOwnProperty( "actions" )) {
         ctxt.actions.length = 0;
         ctxt.actions.push( ...(args as Actions).actions );
      }
      response.end( JSON.stringify( ctxt ));
   }
}
```

The two lines:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-prototype-builtins
if( args && args.hasOwnProperty( "actions" )) {
```

means "if args is defined and has an attribute actions"

How to write it?

I tried `typeof` and `instanceof`, without success.

Comment: `args && "actions" in args`

Comment: more explicit way is to write a type-guard function using `is` in the function declaration https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: @Anatoly: can you give an concise example?
I want an idiom, not a framework :-)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax was given by [pink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/pink) in comments, thanks!

```
type Argument = object | { actions: string[] };

export class GetFilesContext implements IExecutable {

   execute( args: Argument, response: ServerResponse<IncomingMessage> ): void {
      ...
      if( args &&( 'actions' in args )) {
         ctxt.actions.push( ...args.actions );
      }
      response.end( JSON.stringify( ctxt ));
   }
}
```